# Wondering about SWT and Swing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-plugin, swt

Is SWT only in use for Eclipse? Like is it basically Eclipse's version of Swing? I was reading some stuff online when I thought of this.
Ex. http://www.mkyong.com/swt/swt-hello-world-example/

Comment: Np, you can use SWT like any 3rd party library.  Best thing to do is is just try ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is SWT only in use for Eclipse?

No.

> #### SWT: The Standard Widget Toolkit
>
> SWT is an open source widget toolkit for Java designed to provide efficient, portable access to the user-interface facilities of the operating systems on which it is implemented.

http://www.eclipse.org/swt